# Display the enum type in a select box with angular 5 and typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an angular 5 application. I have declared an enum constant 
named DateRange.

```
export enum DateRange {
  TODAY = 'Today',
  THIS_WEEK = 'This Week',
  THIS_MONTH = 'This Month',
  THIS_YEAR = 'This Year'
}
```

I would like to display this enum in my select box in my components html. Any idea how can I achieve it?

I would expect it as follows

```
<select> 
  <option value="TODAY"> Today </option>
  <option value="THIS_WEEK"> This Week</option>
  <option value="THIS_MONTH">This Month </option>
  <option value="THIS_YEAR"> This Year </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define the following in your html:

```
<select> 
   <option *ngFor="let range of Object.keys(ranges)" [ngValue]="range">{{ranges[range]}}</option>
</select>
```

Define the following in your component:

```
ranges= DateRange;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert enum like JS object.

```
Object.values(DateRange); // [ 'Today', 'This Week', 'This Month', 'This Year']
Object.keys(DateRange); // [ 'TODAY', 'THIS_WEEK', 'THIS_MONTH', 'THIS_YEAR' ]
```

now you can show it use *ngFor

Answer (score 1):

you can loop throught the keys of the enum and take them as value of your dropdown 
 like this:

```
<select> 
  <option [value]="key" *ngFor="let key of getKeys(DateRange)">{{ DateRange[key] }}</option>
</select>
```

and i the component.ts you have to add the function `getKeys` like this:

```
getKeys(obj: any) { return Object.keys(obj); }
```

for sure the enum must also be a part of this component...

Answer (score 1):

Define the following in your component:

```
const dateRanges = Object.keys(DateRange).map(key => DateRange[key]);
const selectedDateRange: DateRange = dateRanges[0];
```

Then use it in your template as follows:

```
<mat-form-field> 
    <mat-select placeholder="Date Range" [(value)]="selectedDateRange">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let dateRange of dateRanges" [value]="dateRange">
            {{ dateRange }}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```